# OpenMesh multithreaded mesh import

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmesh

I cannot find any information about thread-safety of OpenMesh operations,
specifically I'm looking for a multithreaded mesh importing. Currently I'm filling my mesh through:

```
OpenMesh::IO::ImporterT
```

In single thread. But if it's possible - I wan't to do this operation in multiple threads, without blocking around:

```
meshImporter.add_face(faceHandle);
meshImporter.add_vertex(vertex);
```

But it's a little bit slower than I thought (It consumes more than half of time of next operation - decimation the of same mesh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the OpenMesh data structures offer thread-safe modification. Operations such as `add_face` or `add_vertex` need to update indices of other element types to keep the data structure in a consistent state. Calling these methods concurrently on the same mesh can thus result in corrupted mesh data.

Since `OpenMesh::IO::ImporterT` mostly forwards its calls to an underlying mesh, the same restrictions apply: All updates to an OpenMesh must be synchronized.